# Is there a way to exclude file patterns from jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

In my React/Redux application, my team has decided we do not want to include containers in our jest coverage reports.

We have been successful with excluding directories, but unsuccessful when excluding files.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to exclude files that end with the word Container in our jest configurations? ex: exampleComponentContainer.jsx should be exluded

Answer (score 11):

You can use `collectCoverageFrom` inside your `package.json` `jest` configuration to exclude `*Container.jsx` files from code coverage.

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "**/*.{js,jsx}",
        "!**/node_modules/**",
        "!**/*Container.jsx"
    ]
}
```

If you use `create-react-app` remove the line `"collectCoverage": true,` which is not supported.

Source: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#collectcoveragefrom-array

Answer (score 1):

For someone trying to something similar in 2022..

In my storybook create-react-app I do this for excluding all .stories files (e.g. "somestory.stories.tsx") from my coverage via the package.json

```
"jest": {    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["^.*\\.stories\\.[jt]sx?$"] }
```